# Error in using svjour3.cls

Tags: document-classes

I need to add the `svjour3.cls` to `TexStudio`. For running the `\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}`.
I tried to find a location to copy it. I put it in several directories as well as my local .TEX file. and it didn't run. I get the following error: `"File`svjour3.cls' not found. \usepackage.' Here is my `TexStudio` directories:
[image]

Comment: Keep it in the same folder as your main TeX file

Answer (score 1):

I saved the source file as `.TEX` and copied to same directory `svjour3.cls` and it works.